# How to differentiate $\sum_{t=0}^{T}$ problem?

Tags: derivatives

Define $F(C, H)=\sum_{t=0}^{T}\beta^t (logC_t+\mu log H_t)$ where $\beta$ and $\mu$ are constant.
I expand this function like $F(C, H)=\beta^0 (logC_0+\mu logH_0)+ \beta^1(logC_1+\mu logH_1)+\dots$
then $A=\frac{dF}{dC_t}=\beta^t \frac{1}{C_t}$, $B=\frac{dF}{dC_{t+1}}=\beta^{t+1} \frac{1}{C_{t+1}}$ and $\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C_{t+1}}{\beta C_t}$
But the answer is $\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C_{t+1}}{C_t}$
Is there any error in my solution?
Actually I don't know how to differentiate this $\sum$ problem... I need your help.

Comment: With respect to which variable are you differentiating? $t$? Your statement is a bit confusing - of what variables is $F$ a function?

Comment: @guest Also note that dlog(a)(u)/dx = du/dxu.lna.

Comment: @ Partick stevens I edited my question and I guess this is a partial derivative problem with $C_t$ and $C_{t+1}$...

Comment: The notation is confusing. You have $t$ 'unbound' on the left but 'bound' on the left.